# How exactly are nucleoli made of NORs?

Tags: cell-biology

I read that nucleoli are made of DNA, RNA, and nucleolus organizer regions. I don't quite understand how that happens with NORs. Isn't there an envelope delimiting the nucleolus from the rest of the nucleus content? Do NORs from different chromosomes come together? I mean, they are not detaching from the rest of the chromosome and aggregating freely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no membrane that separates the nucleolus from the rest of the nucleus. The nucleolus is an aggregate of all kinds of molecules involved with ribosome assembly like: precursor and mature rRNA, Small nucleolar RNAs, rRNA-processing enzymes, ribosomal proteins and partly assembled ribosomes ([but no fully functional ribosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome_biogenesis))

Aside from all these protein and RNA there are indeed regions of the chromosome called [Nucleolus organizer regions (NORs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleolus_organizer_region) present in the nucleolus. These NORs are located near the tips of the short **p** region of chromosome 13, 14, 15, 21, and 22. During [interphase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interphase) these regions [decondensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatin) due to proteins like [nucleolin](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P19338) and are thus open for transcription. Many of the protein I mentioned are needed to form or present in the aggregation that is the nucleolus.

[image]